# Maximum number of connections to a psql database

Tags: c++, database-connection, psql

Is there a limit to create connections to a psql database? I created 10 connections and added them to an array. But when I check each and every connection, it says the connections are broken. Can someone tell me the reason for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate with examples of how you create the connections, and how you are checking the connections? Also, please post code and output examples, as well as your goal as someone may have a better solution than what you are attempting to do.